# How to replace button hover color in XAML and Material Design Xaml Toolkit?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, material-design-in-xaml, wfp

I want to replace the Material Design Xaml button hover color. But i just dont know how to do it please help. Below is my button code...

```
<Button Width="45" Margin="0" Height="40" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Click="MinimizeButton_Click">
     <Button.Style>
       <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
          <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkRed"/>
              </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
     </Button.Style>
     <Image Source="Images/minimize.png" Height="15" Width="15" />
</Button>
```

So how to replace the hover color even if I add a color it didnt work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is already a trigger on **IsMouseOver** in the control template of the MaterialDesignFlatButton which set the **Background** to a color based on the **Foreground**

It is done like this in their style

```
<Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
<Setter TargetName="border" Value="{Binding Foreground , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BrushOpacityConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.16}" Property="Background" />
</Trigger>
```

What you can do is to add also a Foreground change in your trigger if you can live with the fact that the text will also be of this color like below.

[image]

Otherwise you have to override the control template completely to remove this trigger.